# watin dll: other équivalents solutions for parsing web page?

Tags: parsing, web, watin

I  using watin in a wpf c# project for firing clicks on links and parsing pages in   web sites.

It works post part of time but it launchs sometimes exceptions  without raisons ans it is not reallly intuitive .

Do you know équivalents more realiable , intuitive ans with a big community and a good documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one big contender to Watin and it is called Selenium. It is different from Watin and there is a learning curve (you can't just switch to Selenium) but it could suit your needs better (I have VERY stable systems made in Watin and never had an issue with them).

It could help, also, if you post more details about your issue, in the way you asked your question leaves a lot to be desired (what's making it unstable, what portions of the code, what exceptions are you getting, when, etc.)